# Why does TypeScript interpret filtered string array as string | boolean array

Tags: typescript

I've got the following expression

```
[isProduction() && '/prod-path', 'first', 'second'].filter(Boolean)
```

TypeScript does not agree this is a string[]. Could anyone please tell me why?

Comment: `isProduction() && '/prod-path` resolves to either a `false` or a string.

Comment: Obviously, but after the .filter only a string array will remain. So, why..

Comment: The original array is `(boolean | string)[]`. If you filter it, you still going to be `(boolean | string)[]`. TS won't really evaluate that logic you have. Filtering an array that *might* contain a `true` (part of the `boolean`) would still leave a `true`. So, type-wise, TS is correct. You use knowledge TS doesn't have - that it's `(false | string)[]`.

Comment: Overall, I'm not sure why this isn't just `if (isProduction()) arr.unshift('/prod-path')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.filter` function has an overload for the return value of the result which looks like this

```
filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => any, thisArg?: any): T[];
```

Since your array is of type `T == (string | boolean)[]` it will return that type. However you can use type guards to change the return type e.g.

```
function isNotBool<T>(argument: T | boolean): argument is T {
    return typeof argument !== "boolean"
}

const test:string[] = [isProduction() && '/prod-path', 'first', 'second'].filter(isNotBool);
```

Answer (score 3):

If isProduction is false, you end up with:

```
[false, 'first', 'second']
```

which is as Typescript says, an `Array<string|boolean>`.

The filter won't filter out boolean on the type level. You'll have to manually say it like so:

```
.filter((item):item is string => Boolean(item))
```

Comment: Aha, I see. Kind of funky, but I see your point. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This way it remains as string[] by default

```
const s = ['first', 'second']

if (isProduction()) {
    s.push("/prod-path")
}
```

Comment: Defeats the purpose of Typescript if you tell him things that are not true.

Comment: Not really an answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way:

```js
[
  ...(isProduction() ? ['/prod-path'] : []),
  'first',
  'second',
]
```